# react-native-reanimated useDerivedValue does not modify the dom

Tags: react-native, animation, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I have the simplest example possible with `useDerivedValue`:

A `SharedValue` that is modified when scrolling.

A derived `boolean` value based on this scroll position

```
const isShown = useDerivedValue(() => {
  console.log('y', currentPositionY.value);
  return currentPositionY.value > 40;
}, [currentPositionY]);
```

The `y` is logged and modified as it should.

A component that should display a different text based on this boolean:

```
const TestC = ({ isShown }: { isShown: SharedValue<boolean> }) => {
  console.log('isS', isShown.value);

  if (isShown.value) {
    return <Text>shown</Text>;
  } else {
    return <Text>not shown</Text>;
  }
};
```

But the `TestC` component is not updated following the derived value.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Albeit a little old I think [this blog](https://formidable.com/blog/2021/reanimated-two/) does a good job of breaking down the native thread vs. the js runtime. I bring this up because understanding this bridge and how we need to consider accessing these native runtime values in our JSX components will make this issue a little more obvious.

Here are some things you can try to solve this:

- [animated props](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/api/hooks/useAnimatedProps) - could make your example work as is
- [animated styles](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/api/hooks/useAnimatedStyle) - this approach would be good if you wanted to effect styles explicitly
- [worklets](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/worklets) - big guns approach and larger learning curve